# Using serilog without MessageFormat

Tags: .net, serilog

As far as I can tell if I want the log output to be

```
{
  "timestamp":"<the time>",
  "action":"my_action",
  "state":"my_state"
}
```

I have to write

```
logger.Information(
  "{action}{state}",
  "my_action","my_state");
```

This gets messy quickly, especially wrt the disconnect between the "key" and the "value"

Is there something similar to

```
logger.UNKNOWN_FUNC(
  new { 
   action="my_action",
   state="my_state"
  });
```

Comment: If you're trying to slip arbitrary items into the LogEvent's property dictionary, the `.ForContext` methods on the ILogger provide for that (and enrichers in general). If you are looking for something that's still part of the general idiom of a message template and putting fields in, people experiment with the lower level interface used by string interpolation, but that's flaky hack territory, and there's definitely not a widely used scheme you just haven't found yet.

Comment: ok. I just don't find any value in the MessageFormat, just the structured log

Comment: It'll certainly work as an efficient engine in that mode, but I'd have a read of serilog.net to see if you can find any style / aspects that do make sense before you give up - it's not like it's optimised around spitting out chatty "class A got to line 20" messages. I use it pretty sparingly in https://github.com/jet/equinox, and definitely do pack a lot of data into fields in a way that sounds similar to your intent. But it may be that your interests or needs are more aligned with telemetry/metrics type tooling. Anyway, scan the wiki; `ForContext` and Enrichers are the general direction..

Comment: I'll look at that project. " needs are more aligned with telemetry/metrics type tooling", yes that's me. I never wish to see "class A got to line 20" in logs